# error while loading file in dom php

Tags: php, dom

I am using the below code to create a div <-- successfully. The problem is when i try to create a child div and select $pagenameselected.php to load. Here I get an error because when it loads $pagenameselected <-- it load the php script to create the div and not the created div like i can see in page source.

```
 <?php
 $myfile = fopen("../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $x = "<?php " . '$dom' . "= new DOMDocument();" .
 '$element' . "= " . '$dom' . "->createElement('div', '$textcon');" .
 '$dom' . "->appendChild(" . '$element' . ");
 echo " . '$dom' . "->saveXML();?>";
 fwrite($myfile,$x);
 fclose($myfile);
 ?>

 $myfile = fopen("../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $file = $DOCUMENT_ROOT. "../userfolders/$email/$ongrassdb/$pagenameselected.php";
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
 $doc->loadHTMLFile($file);
 //$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is expecting an HTML document,   you are sending it a PHP document.

instead of using the $x =

You should just do this ...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$ele = $dom->createElement('div', $textcon);
$dom->appendChild($ele);
$html = $dom->saveXML();

fwrite($myfile, $html);
```

Comment: thanks man, i have changed the code to create the primary div to your code, its excellent, can you also let me know please , how could i create a child div on this by selecting the page brother.

Comment: Glad it worked, can you mark the answer correct by clicking the checkmark under the 0.   Im new on here trying to build up rep.    Can you update your original question with some details on the child div you asked about.   You want a div inside the div you created?  Is that what your saying?

Comment: please tell me how to add a child div to this

Comment: OK, I will.  I  had to step out for a while,  let me see what I can figure out.